# Track email activity in C# code

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using sendgrid to send email. I can see sent mails activities in my sendgrid portal. Now I want track those activities in my c# code. Like what happened to mail - > delivered or bounced or blocked. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using Sendgrid Events and it turns out to be rather simple.

Check out https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html

You can decide how you want the receive the events, in my case I selected JSON.

In your C# web application, you can create a class like:

```
public class EmailEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("sg_message_id")]
    public string MessageId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("smtp-id")]
    public string smtpid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("event")]
    public string Event { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userid")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller action like:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> IncomingNotification([FromBody] EmailEvent[] events)
{
    // be prepared to handle an array of events as sendgrid can send batches
}
```

You are free to name the action the way you want as long at it matches how you configured the SendGrid webhook.

Comment: But which API is used to get those properties?

Comment: The idea is that you can instruct SendGrid to POST to your own API. The code provided shows how you can build the endpoint that will be called. In SendGrid, go to Settings and enable Event Notification. You will see a place where you can add your own callback url.

Comment: I provided my url in sendgrid and trying to test integration. But it is not giving any output. Like my breakpoint is not getting hitted. Is there any other setting that I am missing?

Comment: The url must be public for SendGrid to be able to call it. Since you are talking about a breakpoint, I'm guessing that you are running your web site on your local machine and that would be why it is not working. To test locally you could use a tool like ngrok.

Comment: Good to know! So.. you instruct SendGrid to call an URL on your site and get notified when something relevant happens.. 
But.. is it also possible the reverse? 
That is, a kind of "one shot" query on email events, maybe filtering on some unique parameter we passed when sending the message?

Comment: @Luke It would depend on what you are looking for. If you want to query the invalid emails, you could use this endpoint: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/invalid_emails.html

Comment: @Luke As far as I know, SendGrid does not store the content of the emails that have been sent so any search based on that would not be possible.

Comment: @FrancoisBeaussier thanks! I don't need the contents, just a way to tell if a specific email I sent was sent correctly or if for some reason was not sent or bounced back to sender.. seems that the only way is the webhook.. :(